# In Bitbucket.org is there a way to modify a file in history

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Is it possible to change a commit in mercurial. For security reasons we would like to remove previously committed security connection information in all previous commits of the file. Is this possible or will we just have to delete and reupload the repository?

Update:it sounds like histedit is the way to do this, but when I do

```
hg histedit revisionnumberstring
```

I'm getting

```
comparing with revisionnumberstring
abort: repository revisionnumberstring not found!
```

how do I use the hg histedit to remove the credentials on the initial commit, found in the index.xml file of the root directory?

Comment: Even if you delete and reupload the repository you should consider those credentials compromised and change them immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to histedit the repository, which means essentially to create a new commit for every commit based on a compromised one - and stripping all compromised ones on the server.

See help on `hg histedit` for details.

However removing the info doesn't undo the breach, you should change the leaked credentials anyway.

Comment: I've attempted to use hg histedit, but I am getting repository not found on the revision, could you expound on your answer for useage @planetmaker?